# 404 path for php document

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a .htaccess file with an ErrorDocument 404 that redirects me to a PHP page. My goal is to get the user's entered url, e.g.:
User enters: https://test.de/example //not available
He gets redirected to https://test.de/test.php and I need the old path /example

Comment: `404 Not Found` is not the right code for redirections. You'll need `301 Moved Permanently`, `307 Temporary Redirect` or `308 Permanent Redirect`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's a bit misleading, but they mean an "_internal_ redirect". (Strictly speaking, it's an "internal subrequest".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

In this file you can retrieve the old path (/example) with

```php
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Comment: The whole question context is a bit confusing. This isn't a redirection. The user will not see `404.php` anywhere in his browser. `REQUEST_URI` contains the URL requested by user as usual.

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']` in the error document to retrieve the requested URL-path only. And `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` for the query string.